# How can I delete Skype chat history? version 2.2.0.35 - Linux/Fedora14

Tags: skype

I just can't find any solution to delete the Skype chat history! There is no "Clear History" function in the mentioned version of Skype..

Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for folder `.skype` rename it to something else like `skype.bak` (or just delete it). Then restart Skype.

You will need to re-enter your username and password. Your chat history should now be clear.